# rvm install fails with "awk: can't open file -l"

Tags: bash, rvm

I'm trying to use rvm like so:

`$ rvm install ruby-2.3.1`

It seems to run, for a bit, but then fails with:

`awk: can't open file -l`

What's up here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might not have anything to do with `rvm`, but I can resolve the issue by running under a clean `sh` shell. If I try running this command in either `zsh` or `bash`, it fails as detailed above. Note that `zsh` and `bash` are the 2 shells I use all the time, while I never run `sh`. So I feel it's something in my dot files that's causing it.